# Select complex colour range for skin-colour detection in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am trying to make skin-colour detection program. Basically, it takes video from webcamera, and then creates a mask, after which only the skin should be visible. I have found [a criterium for detecting skin-colour ranges](http://academic.aua.am/Skhachat/Public/Papers%20on%20Face%20Detection/RGB-H-CbCr%20Skin%20Colour%20Model%20for%20Human%20Face%20Detection.pdf) in a paper. It looks like this:

> The skin colour at uniform daylight illumination rule is defined as 
>   (R > 95 ) AND (G > 40 ) AND (B > 20 ) AND (max{R, G, B} - min{R, G, B}
>   15) AND (|R - G| > 15 ) AND (R > G) AND (R > B) (1) while the skin colour under flashlight or daylight lateral illumination rule is given
>   by (R > 220 ) AND (G > 210 ) AND (B > 170 ) AND (|R - G| <= 15 ) AND
>   (R > B) AND (G > B)

What I did in Python is:

```
def check(list):
return ( ( (list[2]>95) and (list[1]>40) and (list[0]>20)) and ((max(list)-min(list))>15)       
        and (abs(list[2]-list[1])>15) and (list[2]>list[1]) and (list[2]>list[0]))

def check2(list):
    return (list[2]>220) and (list[1]>210) and (list[0]>170) and (abs(list[2]-list[1])<=15) and ((list[2]>list[0]) and (list[1]>list[0]))

(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
img=frame   
img=img.tolist()
skinmask =  [[(1 if (check(list) or check2(list)) else 0) for list in l1] for l1 in img]
mask=np.array(skinmask, dtype = "uint8")
skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([frame, skin]))
```

But it is not, what I really expected. It slows the process. I found `cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)` but it can not handle such complex colour-range rules.
Is there any other method to do this in more efficient way?

Comment: You could try benchmarking with the use of `all` and `any` instead of `and`s you have in your check functions. But the code is as simple as it gets, there's not a lot of optimizations that catch the eye. The biggest optimization you can do is to get rid of `skinmask`. And even then the only thing I can think of is to throw those loops to C/C++ because running through all the pixels in the image will take a second-two (depends on the image size).

Comment: I chose Python (not Java, C++ or others) for much faster prototyping and development process. I really wonder, why so famous thing as OpneCV has no built-in functions for that will deal with that. Maybe there exist any other tool or library that have similar functions to OpenCV?

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that. But 'np.array.where' will return me array which contains _only_ elements that are under condition. But I need some kind of filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck here is that you are converting the numpy array `frame` returned by `camera.read()` (i.e. the snapshot made by the camera) into an ordinary Python list. You're then iterating over the elements using ordinary for-loops, which are relatively slow by comparison.

What you should do is use numpy's vectorized operations to get the execution time down.

Your example, slightly rewritten (`list`-> `px`) for clarity and *corrected for the color channels* (the red pixel is at `px[0]`, not `px[2]`):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

def check(px):
    R, G, B = px
    return ( ((R > 95) and (G > 40) and (B > 20))
        and ((max(px)-min(px))>15) and (abs(R - G) > 15) and
        (R > G) and (R > B))

def check2(px):
    R, G, B = px
    return ((R >220) and (G > 210) and (B > 170) and
        (abs(R - G) <= 15) and (R > B) and (G > B))

def iterate_over_list(img):  # your method
    img = img.tolist()
    skinmask =  [[(1 if (check(px) or check2(px)) else 0) for px in row] for row in img]
    return skinmask
```

This can be rewritten in a vectorized form as:

```
def vectorized_form(img):
    R,G,B = [img[:,:,x] for x in range(3)]
    delta15 = np.abs(R.astype(np.int8) - G.astype(np.int8)) > 15  # watch out for np.abs(R-G): because of the UNsigned numbers, they could get clipped!
    more_R_than_B = (R > B)
    is_skin_coloured_during_daytime = ((R > 95) & (G > 40) & (B > 20) &
        (img.ptp(axis=-1) > 15) & delta15 & (R > G) & more_R_than_B)
    is_skin_coloured_under_flashlight = ((R > 220) & (G > 210) & (B > 170) &
        ~delta15 & more_R_than_B & (G > B))
    return np.logical_or(is_skin_coloured_during_daytime, is_skin_coloured_under_flashlight)
```

Note that you can get rid of at least one *logical and* operation: `more_R_than_B` appears in each of the checks, which are then combined using the *logical or* operation. In truth table syntax: `(A & B) | (C & B) == (A | C) & B`. But now I'm micro-optimizing, and I wanted to preserve the original form, because it would show the 1-to-1 map with the paper you cited.

Timing considerations on my system show a speed increase of a factor ~19. Remark, my test image had shape `(480, 640, 3)`. The speed increase will be considerably larger for larger images, because in your method, you iterate over the pixels using the standard Python for-loops, whereas I'm simply using vectorized routines.

```
In [27]: %timeit iterate_over_list(frame)
1 loops, best of 3: 321 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit vectorized(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped, but I should mention, that `R,G,B = [frame[:,:,x] for x in range(3)]` should be changed to `B,G,R = [frame[:,:,x] for x in range(3)]` , because OpenCV returns image in BGR (not RGB) format.

Comment: @aGGeRReS Good you added that piece of information, I'm sure it'll be of use for future readers.

Comment: And I still wondered, why OpenCV don't have any built-in function for such complex colour-range selection. Maybe it's time to write them?